# How to use a surface mesh parameterization?

Tags: c++, mesh, 3d

I'm currently playing with the [surface mesh parameterizations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html) of the C++ library **CGAL**.

For a mesh with a boundary, the computed uv-space (parameterization domain) is either a disk or a square, and so it is easy to deal with. I use the parameterization to map a texture to my meshes, for example a checkerboard:

[image]

But for meshes without boundary, the parameterization method is the so-called *orbifold tutte embedding* and it computes an uv-space which has not a nice shape, for example see [figure 72.12 here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html#Surface_mesh_parameterizationBorderless) (although this space is not so strange for this example, it is almost rectangular, but it can be totally misshapen in general).

So I don't know how to deal with such a space, how to use it to map a texture? For a square or circular space this is easy, I just fill this space with a checkerboard and I map the colors with the correspondence between the uv-coordinates and the vertex coordinates. But how to deal with a misshapen space?

Comment: Do you have example code for the thing that works and the thing that doesn't? An MWE would be useful here.

Comment: There's no thing which does not work. Everything works. I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. This is a question about the usage of a parameterization. If you really want examples, there are numerous ones in the link I gave.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? Is the problem that you are having trouble filling the non-square (u,v) domain with a checkerboard pattern? Is this because of the shape of the domain itself or is it because of how it's meshed in the (u,v) domain? What is your method for checkering a "normal" domain?

Comment: A "normal" domain is either square or circular, so I can draw a checkerboard on it and map it to the surface mesh. But here the domain has a totally irregular shape. @Sardine

Comment: How do you draw this checkerboard? Do you rely on the analytical parameterization of the domain (use explicitely the fact it's a disc/square)? Or do you work with the (u,v) mesh that CGAL provides (basing off picture to the right of checkered hands in the link you provide)? How do you describe this checkering in terms of data? Is it color values at mesh vertices?

Comment: @Sardine Take a look at this article on my blog for a radial checkerboard: <https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/Enneper-checkerboard.html>.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you generate a mesh in (u,v) space using an analytical function. Could you perhaps apply the same approach to a domain that is a superset of the "bad" domain and then trim it using the "bad" domain's boundary as a trimming loop? Perhaps CGAL offers this functionality, this is a common operation in CAD models (trimmed NURBS).